# Problema com o UTF-8

Tags: php, javascript, html

Boas. Eu estou a fazer um projeto, e tenho várias acentuações no meu texto. Já meti :

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

no meu código e ainda assim nada fez e não compreendo o porque ... Alguma ajuda ??
 [image: print 1]

[image: print 2]

Comment: As alternativas vem de alguma base de dados? Se sim, qual e como é feita a conexão?

Comment: Não simplemente apenas é texto que introduzi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não basta apenas definir o charset. O seu arquivo .html (ou qualquer outra extensão) precisa estar codificado como UTF-8. Abra ele em um editor de códigos (como o notepad++, phpstorm, netbeans...) e verifique seu "encoding".

Talvez seu arquivo esteja como ANSI, basta converter para UTF-8.

Existe um ótimo artigo na net sobre isso: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: estou a usar o Eclipse Mars .. Sabe me dizer como verificar lá ?

Comment: @Paulo Nunca utilizei o Eclipse Mars, mas parece que é em: `Window->Preferences->General->Workspace` e lá tem uma parte de `Text file encoding` que você deve marcar: `Other` e colocar UTF-8

Comment: Eu selecionei o meu código inteiro, e fiz o mesmo negócio, mas ainda não deu .. infelizmente. penso que tenho que usar o HTML ententies

Comment: não se trata de selecionar seu código, faz o seguinte, baixe o notepad++, ele tem a opção de converter o encoding dos arquivos de forma rápida e fácil, seu problema será resolvido.

Comment: valeu ! tinha mesmo que o baixar, mas ao menos o problema ficou resolvido

Answer (score 2):

Olá,

Caso uses o notepad++, por exemplo, segue-se um exemplo de como colocares os teus ficheiros em UTF-8:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desta forma os teus ficheiros passam a ser codificados para UTF-8 e preparados para acentuação.

Cumps,

Comment: Estou a utilizar o Eclipse com Aptana plugin, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Mas eu usei o notepad e o erro ficou resolvido !